# How to let google user see the group they have membership without being admin

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I am using google api for user to login. I could make oauth already and I can get access token from user to let them use my service

But I want to display current user groups s/he has membership

I can't use admin sdk because that user is not admin and has no permission to get list of group

Are there any api to get list of groups that user exist? Or are there anyway to have master access token to use admin SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Google Groups API that non-admins can use. However, you can configure your application to use the user's authorization for most requests, but use an admin's authorization for requests to the Admin SDK.

Comment: So how can I keep admin authorize key in the server?

Comment: It depends on the client library you are using, but they all provide the ability to serialize the OAuth2 token to a string or data structure that you can store.